# ROS inside part of a c++ project

Tags: ros, c++, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I've a c++ project where I'm using CMakeList with the structure similar to:

```
Project (inside my ros sandbox)
|
|_Folder1
|___some code
|___CMakeLists.txt
|
|_Folder2
|___some code
|___CMakeLists.txt
|
|_ROS package folder
|___some code
|___CMakeLists.txt
|
|_CMakeLists.txt
```

Inside de main CMakeLists.txt I've something similar to:

> add_subdirectory(recruiter)
>
> add_library(something_static STATIC ${RECRUITER_SOURCES})

Where inside "recruiter" directory is the ROS package, created using "roscreate-pkg".

And I'm getting the following error:

[rosbuild] Error from directory check: /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py  /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/test/noderecruiter
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py", line 46, in 
raise Exception
Exception
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:102 (message):
[rosbuild] rospack found package "test" at "", but the current
directory is "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/test/noderecruiter".  You
should double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found
in the correct precedence order.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:177 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
server/noderecruiter/CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

What's happening?
THanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65801/ros-inside-part-of-a-c++-project/) by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-06-24**:
Are you building with catkin? I think ROS/catkin needs the toplevel.cmake to work.

**Comment by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on 2013-06-24**:
No, I would like to build like a normal project.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-24**:
Could you please post your CMakeLists.txt file in full? It would be good to see the context of your build output.

**Comment by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on 2013-06-25**:
What CMakeLists do you want? The file inside the main project or the ros one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS packages are not designed to simply be included inside CMake packages. This is not a supported use case.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1